# What should a node.js server directory structure look like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have a simple node.js + express server.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

That code is in a file called web on my linux home directory. All my files like photos or my index.html is in the public file. It looks like this:

```
   [web]

     ↓

  [public] , server.js , creatdb.js

     ↓ 

index.html, jquery.js, index.js, photo.jpeg, mydb.db
```

I'm wondering if this is the "correct" way to organize my files or if I should structure it differently.

I want to be able to have sql inserted when for example, something is triggered on my index.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `public` folder should contain only static content. I don't think you'll ever want to return your database as a response from the browser, so it really shouldn't be there. Place it in another folder (one named database, for example).

As for the pages, it's a convention to place them in a `views` folder that should be created on the same level as your `public` folder, but since your html is static, it should be fine the way it is

Comment: What makes a file static?

Comment: When it doesn't change between requests. Your .jpeg files won't change after someone requests them, so they're static. Being so, the server knows it and can cache the response

Comment: If I create a file called views and put my index.html + any other pages in there my localhost wont find them. Do I have to add another file link in my server.js?

Comment: You shouldn't place them there unless you're doing some processing on the page before sending it back to the browser. If you just need to return the file, keep them in your `public` folder